# Transaction Rules reordering - is this a good idea?

Tags: genexus

If you have a Transaction with complex rules, it can difficult to 'manage' them logically inside the rules section because the order they execute is most likely not the order in which they appear in the rules.  You can turn on Detailed Navigation and see the Evaluation Tree, but I was thinking there could be an improvement in this area.

What if there was a model Preference or object Preference that you could set that would, after specification, reorder the rules in the code to match the Evaluation tree?  There could be some clear comments about when things happen, and I would be fine with seeing these 'timing comments' with nothing in them so I knew when rules would fire and when they would not.

We use a Pattern for our KBs and manipulation of rules, events, etc, is already happening, so in this case those would not be changed.  But the manually added rules (outside the pattern's rules) could be reordered.

Also, if the 'timing comments' are inserted, this could be helpful for developers in exposing the time slots that are available instead of having to refer to the wiki repeatedly.

Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. There are almost two reasons for that, the first one is technical: GeneXus executes the rules "in order" (how they were placed in rules) when they match the triggering criteria. So, maybe reordening the rules will produce unexpected behaviour in your application. You could argue that GeneXus would let those rules where they were placed, but, it is still dangerous.

The second one has to do with our "way of programming". I put a lot of comments in the code, I like comments, even in the rules. If GeneXus reorders the rules, how do it knows which comments belongs to which rule. At least for me, I don't like that a "tool" reorganize/reorder my code. And I bet I'm not the only one.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I am sure you are right - others would feel this way.  The 'solution' would have to be controlled by the developer.

I think I would rather have the rules appear in the order GX would execute them than my own, or at least the chance to have GX reorder them that way when I say.  I do not know why they could not do it and I think it would be helpful to new GX developers and in complex situations.

You have a good point on comments.  Maybe the comment stays with line of code directly below it.